# How to filter a list of strings based on the number of uppercase letters?

Tags: python

How could I display data that has 2 uppercase letters such as "LqdhariT"

```
data_list = ["98109sdi72", "ais87sdh1", "09821hadi", "hgatruarr", "xkayTakadaPKN", "z9ai8daohad", "q",
             "qkkudsfids3", "tG8012khasd", "ioawuywe", "aqteyegr", "a", "1", "yta", "swqer", "puytar",
             "sx153iar", "vcdsaqurr", "gykhdia", "weqw256465", "equtr", "hhnjklhad", "yatr", "oiu012ih",
             "yataraK", "HaH", "jadK", "iuoiudoa97asdfa", "ioiuodsa", "Kkdaj","iuoiaiua", "oiopjpiayra",
             "1jhkjakjdgar", "nhbvddwqsf", "iuoiaura0", "9801923nna", "7647", "kiraKi", "ouoiaoiad1",
             "zswqKHAIARAja", "yhty", "kueroiuasd", "iariKakdaQ", "x1", "hhyrtG", "xkaryTR4", "asweq",
             "o0192yhasda", "iuoaida", "v", "uoiuoidasa", "i1231har12", "98a09da", "azk", "iouoiadakda",
             "j", "761HUhayK", "kadaduf", "kaanc", "h", "iad", "z", "atadydsa", "iuoai", "iuadada",
             "Lkauda", "urahK", "7yarkK", "zaqwetya", "sdfe", "hasWesW", "iaoida", "ahara", "kwyack",
             "iaidja", "ii3hKIIada", "irajYta2W", "ikdajr", "zawhdyadg", "kerTRE", "iuoiuo2K", "sdeWKrai",
             "kadauyhyk", "kjxkanhg", "kada", "aKajQ", "kadYT", "LqdhariT"]
```

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Show us what you tried, what you got and what you expected to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with a condition on the case:

```
out = [item for item in data_list if sum(map(str.isupper, item))==2]
```

explanation:

For each item in the list, `map` the `str.upper` function to each character and count the number of uppercase using `sum`. If the count is equal to 2, keep the item.

output:

```
['HaH',
 'iariKakdaQ',
 'xkaryTR4',
 'hasWesW',
 'irajYta2W',
 'sdeWKrai',
 'aKajQ',
 'kadYT',
 'LqdhariT']
```